# MySql: Referencing columns from main query in subquery

Tags: mysql

the following table is supposed to reflect the storage location (stockId) of
purchases, where a purchase is received in parts at different times. (I omitted the date column.)

```
CREATE TABLE stock (purchaseNo INT NOT NULL, quantity INT NOT NULL, stockId INT NOT NULL)
```

Let's say purchase 10 has arrived in three parts and is stored at two different locations (5 and 6).

```
INSERT INTO stock VALUES(10, 2000, 5)
INSERT INTO stock VALUES(10, 3000, 5)
INSERT INTO stock VALUES(10, 1000, 6)
```

Now I would like to select those stocks having more than 2000 kg (quantity) available. This can be done with

```
SELECT stockId AS id, SUM(quantity) AS q
FROM stock
WHERE purchaseNo=10
GROUP BY stockId
HAVING q>2000
```

But since I am only interested in the stockId, I would like to prevent the quantity to be returned as well. Is this possible?
One of my failing attempts is

```
SELECT stockId AS id
FROM stock
WHERE purchaseNo=10 AND (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stock WHERE purchaseNo=10 AND stockId=id) >2000
```

with or without GROUP BY the following error is returned:

`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Remove `SUM(quantity) AS q` from your query.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `SUM` to `HAVING` and skip it from the results.

```
SELECT stockId AS id
FROM stock
WHERE purchaseNo=10
GROUP BY stockId
HAVING SUM(quantity)>2000;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/459a63/1) example.

Comment: Ouu! That simple! Thank you, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT distinct S1.stockId AS S1.id from stock S1
inner join(
SELECT S2.stockId AS S2.id, SUM(S2.quantity) AS S2.q
FROM stock S2
WHERE S2.purchaseNo=10
GROUP BY S2.stockId
HAVING S2.q>2000)
on S1.stockId=S2.stockId
```